# linked-list display last to first in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, display

good day ... i want to make a linked list to display the list from last to first in c++ 
as ii add 29->36->15->1
i wanted to be 1->15->36->29 like this i did the usually one

```
void DisplayNormal()
    {
        linkedlist *temp;
        temp = head;

        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {

            cout << "list Number : " << temp->ListNum << endl;
            cout << "Student Ceel Phone  : " << temp->number << endl;
            cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (temp->next == NULL)
        {
            cout << "list Number : " << temp->ListNum << endl;
            cout << "Student Ceel Phone  : " << temp->number << endl;
            cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I recommend you read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then maybe re ask your question.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to add each item to the beginning of the list instead of the end.

Comment: What about using a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). Which iterates backwards quite naturally, at the cost of one extra pointer per node.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little hard to understand your question.
You means if datas are 29->36->15->1 in linked list then display it 1->15->36->29 or if datas are given 29, 36, 15, 1 in regular sequence, you want to make linked list 1->15->36->29?

I guess you want first one.
So I recommend to use recursive function.

```
typedef struct linkedlist linkedlist;
struct linkedlist{
    int data;
    struct linkedlist* next;
};
void displayReversed(linkedlist* current ) {

  if( current == NULL ) return;
  displayReversed(current->next);
  cout << current->data << endl;
}
```

Comment: Good point! Bob Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way to do it is to reverse linked list **before** and **after** displaying, because we change direction of the **original** linked list, **not** of it's **copy**. You can reverse linked list in O(n), display all the elements in O(n), that's why final time complexity of the algorithm is O(n).

```
class Node
{
    Node *next;
    int val;
};
```

With my this representation of linked list, you can do it this way:

```
Node* reverseLinkedList(Node *head)
{
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *current = head;
    Node *next;
    while (current) {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next; 
    }
    head = prev;
}
```

And your complete function is:

```
void DisplayReversed(Node *head)
{
    reverseLinkedList(head);

    displayNormal(*head);

    reverseLinkedList(head);
}
```